# extract contacts account displayname from account using High order function

Tags: json, swift

this is part 2 from the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451539/extract-contacts-from-account-using-high-order-function). I want to tag an account's display name to each contact. I am not looking for a group by account's display name

swift code

```
self.contacts = result.accounts.map(\.contacts!).flatMap{$0}
self.filteredContacts = self.contacts
self.accountDisplayName = result.accounts.map(\.displayName).flatMap{$0}
self.filteredAccountDisplayName = self.accountDisplayName
```

Json

```
{
   "Accounts":[
      {
         "AccountID":"ef391c24-ad5b-4dca-98ae-b55793dfc029",
         "Contacts":[
            {
               "AccountID":"ef391c24-ad5b-4dca-98ae-b55793dfc029",
               "AvatarImage":"",
               "ContactEmail":"cbacon@associates.com",
               "ContactID":"f74d3810-625f-43d4-afd4-89346a73f807",
               "ContactTitle":"Chief Executive Officer",
               "DisplayName":"Ch  Bacon",
               "FirstName":"Ch",
               "LastName":"Baco",
               "ManagedByStakeholderID":"97e5f0d5-df0d-48fe-bbbb-cccf251f4175",
               "Notes":"OWNER",
               "Roles":[
                  {
                     "RoleEnvironmentName":"",
                     "RoleEnvironmentTenantName":"",
                     "RoleID":"3a824b1e-26d6-41c5-8336-4b79f0962c38",
                     "RoleName":"Environment Administrator"
                  }
               ],
               "StakeholderID":"97e5f0d5-df0d-48fe-bbbb-cccf251f4175",
               "id":"f74d3810-625f-43d4-afd4-89346a73f807"
            }
         ],
         "DisplayName":"Chris Associates Ltd."
      },
      {
         "AccountID":"C31ACAD6-0E5D-43E0-B1A2-E51FD46BFE3A",
         "Contacts":[
            {
               "AccountID":"C31ACAD6-0E5D-43E0-B1A2-E51FD46BFE3A",
               "AvatarImage":"http://www.image.com/",
               "ContactEmail":"jhgjhg@njkjk.com",
               "ContactID":"28fad61f-9a47-41db-888e-19d66de96638",
               "ContactTitle":"",
               "DisplayName":"fvdfvdf",
               "FirstName":"dfvdfv",
               "LastName":"dfvdfv",
               "ManagedByStakeholderID":"97e5f0d5-df0d-48fe-bbbb-cccf251f4175",
               "Notes":"",
               "Roles":[
                  
               ],
               "StakeholderID":"43d3af87-fd21-404c-9af6-2998e401fcb8",
               "id":"28fad61f-9a47-41db-888e-19d66de96638"
            }
         ],
         "DisplayName":"adidas "
      },
      {
         "AccountID":"A4FBDC11-AB07-47BD-8364-0B1D81D8E38F",
         "Contacts":[
            {
               "AccountID":"A4FBDC11-AB07-47BD-8364-0B1D81D8E38F",
               "AvatarImage":"http://www.image.com/",
               "ContactEmail":"jeff@linkedin.com",
               "ContactID":"c205d05d-c4cf-46b2-a9fd-e85af2f317b9",
               "ContactTitle":"",
               "DisplayName":"Jeff Weiner",
               "FirstName":"Jeff",
               "LastName":"Weiner",
               "ManagedByStakeholderID":"97e5f0d5-df0d-48fe-bbbb-cccf251f4175",
               "Notes":"",
               "Roles":[
                  
               ],
               "StakeholderID":"c6fc9b6e-f857-4ca1-8352-dc55b05a9373",
               "id":"c205d05d-c4cf-46b2-a9fd-e85af2f317b9"
            }
         ],
         "DisplayName":"LinkedIn. Inc "
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am trying to flat data up I want to extract contact and account .for example [(contact, account.DisplayName),(contact2, account.DisplayName1)]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flatMap and then map to join accounts and contacts

```
let values = results.accounts
    .flatMap { account in account.contacts.map { ($0, account.displayName) } }
```

Example

```
let accounts = [
    Account(accountID: "1", displayName: "A", managedByStakeholderID: nil, id: nil,
            contacts: [
                Contact(firstName: "a1", lastName: "a1", displayName: "aa1"),
                Contact(firstName: "a2", lastName: "a2", displayName: "aa2"),
            ]),
    Account(accountID: "2", displayName: "B", managedByStakeholderID: nil, id: nil,
            contacts: [
                Contact(firstName: "b", lastName: "b", displayName: "bb"),
            ])
]
```

yields

> [(Contact: aa1, Optional("A")), (Contact: aa2, Optional("A")), (Contact: bb, Optional("B"))]

Comment: this will create an array of contacts groups by account.displayName [([Contact], String?)] I need  [(Contact, String?)]

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper I have tested this with both the given json and my own array and I get the expected result in both cases